# Why Go GC have some long pauses STW (a few millisecond) in this program？

Tags: go, garbage-collection

In one of our services it was found that gc would occasionally have some long STW (up to 100ms), I wrote a random program and found that it did indeed do this and why. This program sometimes thousands of gc only once a few millimeters of pause.
This program can run up to 100ms STW on my machine.

## go version

```
go version go1.21.3 darwin/amd64
```

## code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "runtime/debug"
    "runtime/trace"
    "time"
)

var quit = make(chan struct{})

func printGcStats() {
    s := debug.GCStats{}
    s.PauseQuantiles = make([]time.Duration, 101)

    lastGc := time.Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
    maxPause := time.Duration(0)

    for range time.Tick(time.Second) {
        debug.ReadGCStats(&s)
        if s.LastGC.Equal(lastGc) || len(s.Pause) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        for i, t := range s.PauseEnd {
            if t.Compare(lastGc) > 0 {
                if s.Pause[i] > maxPause {
                    maxPause = s.Pause[i]
                }
                if s.Pause[i] > time.Millisecond*50 {
                    log.Printf("GC %d  maxPause: %v", s.NumGC, maxPause)
                    quit <- struct{}{}
                    return
                }
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        log.Printf("GC %d  maxPause: %v", s.NumGC, maxPause)
        lastGc = s.LastGC
    }
}

func init() {
    go printGcStats()
}

func write() {
    conn, _ := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, &net.UDPAddr{Port: 9104})
    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    for {
        conn.Write(buf)
    }
}

var rChan = make(chan []byte, 1000)

func read() {
    for x := range rChan {
        _ = x
    }
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("trace.out")
    defer f.Close()
    trace.Start(f)
    defer trace.Stop()

    ln, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{Port: 9104})
    go write()
    go read()
    go func() {
        for {
            buf := make([]byte, 512)
            ln.ReadFrom(buf)
            rChan <- buf
        }
    }()

    <-quit
}
```

## gc trace debug

```
gc 114 @24.897s 0%: 0.058+0.24+0.030 ms clock, 0.94+0.10/0.43/0+0.49 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 115 @25.118s 0%: 0.043+0.41+0.12 ms clock, 0.69+0.092/0.23/0+2.0 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 116 @25.356s 0%: 0.060+0.44+0.015 ms clock, 0.96+0.067/0.23/0+0.25 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 117 @25.576s 0%: 0.054+0.27+0.033 ms clock, 0.86+0.062/0.28/0+0.53 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 118 @25.797s 0%: 0.062+0.18+0.016 ms clock, 1.0+0.088/0.26/0+0.26 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 119 @26.020s 0%: 4.5+8.3+5.7 ms clock, 72+0.096/0.16/0+92 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 120 @26.269s 0%: 0.060+0.26+0.018 ms clock, 0.96+0.051/0.30/0+0.30 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 121 @26.485s 0%: 0.059+0.26+0.053 ms clock, 0.95+0.088/0.22/0.002+0.86 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 122 @26.721s 0%: 0.060+0.26+0.039 ms clock, 0.96+0.042/0.23/0.001+0.62 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
gc 123 @26.958s 0%: 0.054+0.19+0.029 ms clock, 0.87+0.062/0.15/0+0.47 ms cpu, 3->3->1 MB, 4 MB goal, 0 MB stacks, 0 MB globals, 16 P
```

[image: go trace]

The STW pauses should be in the microsecond range.
And the gc cleans up only a few MB of memory.I don't know why it's pausing for milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key causes for long GC pauses in Go are routines that are not coming to a stop when the GC asks them to. (figuratively speaking)

In the code above the `write` function is spinning all the time. It doesn't stop or even takes a break. The GC will wait for the routine to pause and eventually forces it to take a break. That "waiting" can cause the GC pause to last longer.

Over the years Go has improved dealing with spinning routines quite a lot and I couldn't verify from the trace that the GC pause is increased due to waiting on a spinning routine.

---

I ran your program on this machine `go version go1.21.3 darwin/arm64` and the only way to get GC pauses that are anywhere around a few millisecond for the entire GC run is to set GOMAXPROCS to 1 or 2. Not setting GOMAXPROCS we are talking ~250microseconds for the entire run.

Could it be that the mac is busy with something else or throttling due to overheating?

[image]

---

Edit: note that Go doesn't "stop the world" for the entire GC run, only a short time at the end of the GC run to do finalize the run. So there is no "stop the world" for ~250microseconds here. (Just to avoid someone reading this out of the above.)

Comment: How long did you run the program? The vast majority of pause times are around a couple hundred microseconds on my machine as well.
For perspective I also added function to count STW pauses using **debug.ReadGCStats**, which I update in the code above. On both my machine and on a linux server it's about a thousand GCs with a pause of a few milliseconds and can be observed via trace file.

Comment: After I ran this program for a long time, at the moment of roughly 20,000 GCs there was a 100ms long STW pause.

Comment: I didn't run it that long. A couple of seconds. Still I'd look into getting rid of the spinning for loop and see if that does anything. For example write 100 times and then pause for 100ms. For testing you can use time.Sleep for that. In production it is a rare case that you have a spinning routine that never takes a pause and then it is usually a bug (in my experience).

Comment: Since our service is a proxy forwarding program, I wrote a code like this. Based on your suggestion I changed the write for loop to like this **for range time.Tick(time.Microsecond * 100)**. Things not get better, it still has a 4 millisecond STW after hundreds of GCs.

Comment: Note, that a `time.Tick` will tick every 100 microseconds but if the work it needs to do in that time takes longer, the routine still doesn't take any pauses.